# Official raspberry pi keyboard not working on Pi 4

Tags: keyboard, pi-4

[Quick update: Keyboard didn’t work on any other computers so it must be DOA. Thanks for the suggestions.]

Official pi 4 desktop kit arrived this morning. Unboxed and setup but keyboard not working. When keyboard is plugged in neither keyboard or mouse work; mouse works fine when keyboard is not plugged in. Otherwise, pi boots into raspbian and works fine.

Tied keyboard into all 4 USB ports (on its own no other usb devices installed) and still does not work. Replaced the keyboards usb cable with a spare one hanging around and that didn’t work either.

I fear the keyboard is DOA, which is frustrating as I bought the official kit so it would ‘jusk work.

Does anyone have any ideas of what else to try before I contact seller?

Comment: try it in another "computer" - USB keyboards that work in pi would work anywhere else

Comment: Of course! Why didn’t I think of that. Trying now...

Comment: Please edit in whether or not the keyboard works elsewhere.  If it does, I will re-open the question.

Comment: If the keyboard fails to work elsewhere than contact the manufacture in order to get a new one as its broken

Comment: Tried on a few other machines with no luck. Am going to contact the supplier. Thanks for your help.